# DataRow.Field<T>(string Column) кидает ошибку преобразования

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Есть вот такой метод:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> GetColumnsList(OleDbConnection conn, string tableName)
        {
            var columns = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new[] { null, null, tableName, null });
            return columns.AsEnumerable().
                Select(x => new
                {
                    ColumnName = x.Field<string>("Column_Name"),
                    Description = $"Data_Type:{ x.Field<int>("Data_Type")};"+
                                  $"IsNullable:{ x.Field<bool>("IS_NULLABLE")};"+
                                  $"CharacterMaximumLength: { x.Field<int?>("Character_Maximum_Length")};"+
                                  $"CharacterOctetLength: { x.Field<int?>("Character_Octet_Length")}"
        }).ToDictionary(key => key.ColumnName, value => value.Description);
        }
```

Так вот, не могу понять, почему вылетает исключение при попытке использовать `int?`.

Сами по себе колонки в DataTable имеют тип int.

System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

> at
>   System.Data.DataRowExtensions.UnboxT`1.NullableField[TElem](Object
>   value)    at System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field[T](DataRow row,
>   String columnName)    at
>   AccessToMySql.Classes.AccessReader.<>c.<GetColumnsList>b__5_0(DataRow
>   x) in
>   D:\Projects\AccessToMySql\AccessToMySql\Classes\AccessReader.cs:line
>   52    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)    at
>   AccessToMySql.Classes.AccessReader.GetColumnsList(OleDbConnection
>   conn, String tableName) in
>   D:\Projects\AccessToMySql\AccessToMySql\Classes\AccessReader.cs:line
>   51    at AccessToMySql.Classes.AccessReader.ProcessingMdb(String
>   pathToMdb) in
>   D:\Projects\AccessToMySql\AccessToMySql\Classes\AccessReader.cs:line
>   37    at AccessToMySql.Classes.AccessReader.Read() in
>   D:\Projects\AccessToMySql\AccessToMySql\Classes\AccessReader.cs:line
>   26    at AccessToMySql.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   D:\Projects\AccessToMySql\AccessToMySql\Program.cs:line 17

Comment: _Сами по себе колонки в DataTable имеют тип int._ именно поэтому и происходит исключение, что ты пытаешься к int32 развернуть

Comment: Хотя нет, проверил на простом примере: все работает как и ожидается, добавь в вопрос полный текст ошибки со stacktrace

Comment: @Grundy, добавил.

Comment: Data_Type вряд ли int , ведь правда?

Comment: Мда... похоже, там Long нужен был. Long? работает. Нужно было DataTable в дебаггере изучить.

Comment: а какие, например, значения бывают у Data_Type c типом long? ?